# What is the "grade" in geometric algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

I'm reading a book (*Linear and Geometric Algebra*, by Alan Macdonald) where the author uses the term *grade* without ever defining it.  I have a murky sense of what the *grade* of a *blade* may be (a geometric product of *k* orthogonal vectors is called a *blade* of *grade k*), but I have no idea of what the *grade* of a general multivector is.  Does *grade* apply only to *blades*?  If not, what is the definition of *grade*?

Comment: I really enjoyed Alan MacDonald's online material about GA. I look forward to snagging a copy of that book someday :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The short answer

*No*, a general multivector is *not* graded. Only a portion of the elements of the algebra are assigned grades. *Yes* blades are among the elements assigned grades. A blade represents a subspace of $V$, and the grade of that blade is the dimension of the subspace the blade represents.

---

Everything I'm about to say is with regards to an $n$ dimensional quadratic space $V$ with a nondegenerate form.

Hopefully you are familiar with the construction where an orthonormal basis $\{e_i\mid 1\leq i\leq n\}$ for $V$ is used to construct a basis for the Clifford algebra.

The basis for the Clifford algebra is made up from these sets:

$S_0=\{1\}$

$S_1=\{e_i\mid 1\leq i\leq n\}$

$S_2=\{e_ie_j\mid 1\leq i< j\leq n \}$

$S_3=\{e_ie_je_k\mid 1\leq i< j<k\leq n \}$

...

$S_n=\{e_1e_2\cdots e_n\}$

The basis for the Clifford algebra we are talking about is $\cup_{j=1}^n S_j$.

### What a grade is:

> Everything in the vector space $\langle S_i \rangle$ spanned by $S_i$ is said to have grade $i$ (excepting 0 for the time being). Things which are sums of elements of different grades do not have any grade defined for them, and they are said to have *mixed grade*. Grade only applies to things in these special subspaces. The element 0 lies in all of these sets, so one needs to understand 0 as being an exceptional element. (I'm not exactly sure what most references do concerning 0.)

It isn't hard to show that any product of $k$ vectors (vectors, elements of $V$ lie in $\langle S_1 \rangle$) lies in $\langle S_k\rangle$. It turns out that the product is zero exactly when the set of vectors you are multiplying is linearly dependent. Blades, being products like this, do always have a grade.

### What grade roughly means:

For a blade $b_1\cdots b_k$ of $k$ vectors from $V$ made up of linearly independent vectors $b_i$", you get an element of grade $k$. Since this element is usually interpreted as "the subspace of $V$ generated by the $b_i$, you can see that the grade is coinciding with the dimension of this subspace.

When the vectors are not LI, things are different. Had the $b_i$ been linearly dependent, the product $b_1\cdots b_k$ would be zero, but the dimension of the span of the $b_i$ could be anything less than $k$, so you can see why there are problems assigning 0 a fixed grade to make the system of "grade is the same as dimension of span" work universally.

The interesting thing is that multiplication plays well with grades. I think the path most often taken is to just define the grade of 0 to be 0, and then declare "the product of a grade $k$ vector with a grade $j$ vector has grade $j+k$ or grade $0$ according to whether the product is zero or not."

Comment: A multivector that does not consist of terms of a single grade is not said to be ungraded, but rather that it is of *mixed* grade, also.

Comment: @Muphrid That's a good point, it would be good to introduce that. I hope you won't mind if I edit that in.

Comment: Many thanks for an exceptionally helpful answer!

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to the top of p. 97 and also the previous page. See also Definition 6.7 on p. 98.

Alan Macdonald

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty much the same meaning as dimension, with the additional specificty of 'dimension of a multivector (or clif)' in the manner defined by Geometric algebra, i.e. scalar = grade 0, vector = grade 1, bivector = 2, etc. But you can just read it as dimension.